# How do changes in a video file during editing relate to voltage levels?

Tags: voltage, electronics

I’m trying to understand the relationship between video editing and voltage levels. For instance, if I trim the first 10 seconds of an MP4 video file or add an audio track, how are these changes reflected in the voltage levels that represent the file’s binary data?

In other words, when we perform high-level tasks such as cutting a scene or adding an effect in a video, how are these changes encoded as different voltage levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical voltage levels don't change.  When you change a digital file, you change the sequence of binary digits (bits) that it contains.  But each bit is still represented in your computer's memory by some "high" voltage for 1 and "low" voltage for 0.  These high and low voltages are fixed by the physical design of the computer;  they are not inherent to the file you're editing.